# Login into my website with Facebook account but without FB.login()

Tags: facebook-login

Reacntly, I have a project that login our website with facebook jsut like the stackoverflow! 
limits:

1. I can't open a new window! so the function FB.loigin() was dropped!

   FB.login(function(response)
   {
      if(response.status == 'connected'){
      }
   },{scope: 'email'});

So, I only can use the way of <<[Manually Build a Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow?locale=en_US)>> Flow to guild user to login in!
But,when I set redirect_uri like this one:

```
xxx&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
```

when user input the username and password! they redirect to

```
facebook.html/contact/login_success.html
```

can't redirect to my page!!!

SOS!!!

Comment: why not just change the redirect uri then? and why can´t you open a new window? FB.login usually works fine if you do it right.

Comment: Because, I need to insert my page to single webview! FB.login() open a new window so I dropped it!